# Alexa video skill, lambda function is not getting triggered

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I have my videos hosted on my server. I have created a video skill to play those videos on fire TV using alexa video skill API. However, my lambda function is not getting triggered when I say "Alexa, play ". Is there anything else that needs to be done? I haven't done any catalog ingestion nor my videos data are on gracenote. Is this a necessary step?

Comment: capture logs and update in your question

Comment: How can i capture logs if lambda function is not getting triggered. Bro please read the question once again.

Comment: in your alexa skill test .. if you say Alexa, play.. does it play your video? If not it creats a response which you can upload in your question

Comment: @AmodGokhale Have you worked on creating a video skill in Alexa. Creating a video skill is different from custom skill creation.